# Serial port data received event in separate class from the form

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I am using windows application form to receive a data from a serial port. Inside the form I can raise `SerialportDataReceived` event. But what I want is to put the serial port event at a separate class and get the data back to the form.

Here is the the class that contains `eventhandler` for the serial port received data:

```
class SerialPortEvent
{
    public void mySerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
            //no. of data at the port
            int ByteToRead = sp.BytesToRead;

            //create array to store buffer data
            byte[] inputData = new byte[ByteToRead];

            //read the data and store
            sp.Read(inputData, 0, ByteToRead);

        }
        catch (SystemException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Data Received Event");
        }


    }
}
```

How do I link this class to the form when data is received? Do I have to raise the event at the main program or in the form itself?

The way I'm invoking now is below at the main:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());

        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM81");
        SerialPortEvent ReceivedData = new SerialPortEvent();
        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(ReceivedData.mySerialPort_DataReceived);
        myserialPort.open();
    }
```

Nothing is received at the serial port received event.

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't catch `SystemException`. Catch `Exception`, instead. Also, if you want to really know what's going on, display `ex.ToString()`

Comment: You are not going to read much from a *new* SerialPort object.  Cast *sender* to SerialPort to use the instance that actually generated the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your other class define it's own event for the form to handle which can provide the form with the bytes read:

```
class SerialPortEvent
{
    private SerialPort mySerialPort;

    public Action<byte[]> DataReceived;

    //Created the actual serial port in the constructor here, 
    //as it makes more sense than having the caller need to do it.
    //you'll also need access to it in the event handler to read the data
    public SerialPortEvent()
    {
        mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM81");
        mySerialPort.DataReceived += mySerialPort_DataReceived
        myserialPort.open();
    }

    public void mySerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //no. of data at the port
            int ByteToRead = mySerialPort.BytesToRead;

            //create array to store buffer data
            byte[] inputData = new byte[ByteToRead];

            //read the data and store
            mySerialPort.Read(inputData, 0, ByteToRead);

            var copy = DataReceived;
            if(copy != null) copy(inputData);

        }
        catch (SystemException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Data Received Event");
        }
    }
}
```

Next, you don't want to create the `SerialPortEvent` instance in `Main`, you'll want to create it in the main form's constructor or load event:

```
public Form1()
{
    SerialPortEvent serialPortEvent = new SerialPortEvent();
    serialPortEvent.DataReceived += ProcessData;
}

private void ProcessData(byte[] data)
{
    //TODO do stuff with data
}
```

Comment: thanks Servy. it is a logic solution.. but there is an error at the `mySerialPort_DataReceived` method saying :`object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: @Liban You're going to need to be more specific about which line the error is on.

Comment: at the first line. when the program comes to execute the first line which is `int ByteToRead = mySerialPort.BytesToRead;` it throws exception with the message :`object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: @Liban Have you made any changes to the code?  Because as it is it's impossible for that exception to be thrown because the object is initialized in the constructor and never re-assigned.